# Is it possible to 'read' a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

new user, semi-noobie Haskell programmer here. I've been looking through 'Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours' and it occurred to me that, though it would be extremely unsafe in practice, it would be interesting to see if a Haskell program could 'read' a function.

For example, `read "+" :: Num a => a -> a -> a`  -- (that is the type of (+) )

The above example did not work, however. Any ideas? I know this is a really dumb thing to do in practice, but it would be really cool if it were possible, right?

Comment: No, but there are some very difficult and/or tedious ways that you could make it work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this is yes.  The problem is that there are infinitely many functions (Num a) => a -> a -> a.  So you'd have to have a line in your read instance for each of them, if you want complete coverage.  The fact that your read instance wouldn't be total makes this option unappealing.  If you want to parse mathematical expressions, make a language of mathematical expressions and parse and interpret that.  Haskell makes it easy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell is a static and compiled language and you can interpret a string as a function by using [Language.Haskell.Interpreter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html).

A minimal example that reads a binary function with type `Int -> Int -> Int` is:

```
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  -- check that head args exists!
  errorOrF <- runInterpreter $ do
    setImports ["Prelude"]
    interpret (head args) (as::Int -> Int -> Int)
  case errorOrF of
    Left errs -> print errs
    Right f   -> print $ f 1 2
```

You can call this program in this way (here I assume the filename with the code is `test.hs`):

```
> ghc test.hs
...
> ./test "\\x y -> x + y"
3
```

The core of the program is [runInterpreter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v%3arunInterpreter), that is where the interpreter interprets the String. We first add the `Prelude` module to the context with [setImports](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v%3asetImports) to make available, for example, the `+` function. Then we call [interpret](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v%3ainterpret) to interpret the first argument as a function and we use [as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.1.0/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v%3aas) `Int -> Int -> Int` to enforce the type.
The result of `runInterpreter` is a `Either InterpretError a` where `a` is your type. If the result is `Left` then you have an error, else you have your function or value. Once you have extracted it from `Right`, you can use it as you use a Haskell function. See `f 1 2` above, for example.

If you want a more complete example you can check [haskell-awk](https://github.com/gelisam/hawk), that is my and gelisam project to implement a awk-like command line utility that use Haskell code instead of AWK code. We use `Language.Haskell.Interpreter` to interpret the user function.

Comment: `./test (+)` also works. Fortunately `./test "\\x y -> unsafePerformIO (print 0 >> return 5)"` doesn't work without `"System.IO.Unsafe"` added to `setImports`.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is that, no, you cannot. Functions are very "opaque" in Haskell generally—the only way you can analyze them is to apply arguments to them (or use typeclasses to pull information out of the type, but that's different).

This means it's very difficult to create a dynamic function in any sort of specialized or simplified way. The best you can do is embed a parser, interpreter, and serialization/deserialization mechanism to another language and then parse strings of that language and execute them in the interpreter.

Of course, if your interpreted language is just Haskell (such as what you get using the `hint` package) then you can do what you're looking for.

Comment: But he's not trying to analyze a function.  He's asking if he can use read to parse function expressions into functions.  I don't see why not.

Comment: Hint is the right answer, I just wanted to contrast the feel for functions you might get from, say, javascript where their implementation is still quite available and `eval` is a natural construct.